# SAS PROC SQL CREATE Statement not valid or out of order error

Tags: sql, sas, zos

Can anyone help me resolve this error?  It's in SAS 9.2.

```
275          PROC SQL;                                                      
276           CREATE TABLE WORK.MATCHREC AS                                 
              ______                                                        
              180                                                           
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.    
277           SELECT A.*,                                                   
278                  B.DSORG AS MDFLAG FORMAT=$2. LABEL='MATCHED DATA FLAG' 
279           FROM DAILY.SMFLIST A LEFT JOIN WORK.LISTDSN B                 
280           ON (A.DSNAME=B.DSNAME);                                       

281           QUIT;
```

Comment: Your code is fine.  Methinks something above line 275 is causing the error.

Comment: You probably have a missing semicolon above, or something else causing `PROC SQL;` to not work and not cause you to enter the SQL environment.

Comment: @Gordon I'd have to agree. I inserted a run statement immediately before the PROC and it ran. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone want to offer an answer so I can close this?  I am OCD that way...  Wishing everyone was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a run; statement before proc sql resolved the problem.  It must have cleaned up whatever was hanging and interfering with it.